# Blocking Facebook in a system

Tags: windows, blocking, facebook

Is there any possibility to block facebook on a user system without configuring through the server ? is there any coding to be added in somewhere or can we block through a browser ?

Comment: you can use firewall to block any website.
http://superuser.com/questions/270524/blocking-web-sites-with-windows-firewall

Comment: Modify the hosts file to point facebook.com to 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Who are you trying to block? Do they have Admin rights on the computer? Do they have computers knowledge?
If someone is knowledgeable enough he can practically bypass or remove most blocks.

Comment: @EliadTech they all are users i.e Employees and they don't have Admin Previliages.

Comment: You've answered only one of my questions... How skilled are they in computers?

Comment: @EliadTech No and i am a system administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Using the hosts files for stuff like this works in theory (as mentioned by EliadTech) but is considered bad practice. The hosts file does still have it's uses sometimes, but for the most part it is just a 'relic' from the early days of ip-networking.

If you want to block certain domains/url's/ip-addresses for an entire (sub)network I would recommend setting up a (transparent) proxy server.
Besides adding the advantage of hiding your internal machines to the internet and lessening traffic load for much-used sites you can do all kinds of filtering and blocking without having to mess with hosts files on all client machines.

Another advantage is that even skilled users will not be able to easily circumvent this setup without arousing suspicion.

I use Squid alot. It's free, not very hard to configure and has a very lightweight footprint.

Answer (score 0):

You can try what Lawrence suggested, and edit the HOSTS file (which is located here: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\HOSTS), though from my experience solutions with HOSTS file doesn't work properly.

As for what eramit suggested (blocking through the local FW), it is not possible to block URL from the built-in FW (not even in Win7 FW), only IP addresses (which a serious headache for any website in this magnitude).

[In this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/270524/blocking-web-sites-with-windows-firewall) TheCompWiz suggested to use an open DNS or some commercial filtering solution.