# Block Facebook using Windows Firewall not work

Tags: blocking, windows-firewall

I'm trying to block Facebook following this guide but it didn't work. Did you try this way and did it work?

[Blocking web sites with Windows Firewall](https://superuser.com/questions/270524/blocking-web-sites-with-windows-firewall)

Windows Firewall:

[image]

Comment: Can you specify what have you tried? Have you blocked the IPs of both facebook.com and www.facebook.com? Note that facebook has many subdomains and many IP addresses.

Comment: I ping facebook.com to get the IP. Then following the guide. I did for both Inbound and Outbound but it didn't work. How about you? Does it work?

Comment: Did you do it for www.facebook.com as well? They both have different IP addresses.

Comment: Why dont you block it in your router?

Comment: Yes, I have just try to get both IP when ping facebook.com and www.facebook.com but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't have the right to access the router. I just can control my computer. I'm the owner.

Comment: Thanks Ziggy, I don't know why but I retried and this time was successful. I also retried on another machine (virtual) and successful too.