# Avast keeps showing this virus error

Tags: virus, malware, trojan, avast

I don't remember entering any "funny" website and this virus warning seems to pop-up at random once every day, anyone know what it is? How can I fix it?

**Object:** `http://mst.my03.com:8080/k.zip | [Embedded:MSEnc...`

**Infection:**
VBS:Downloader-ABT [Trj]

**Process:** C:\Windows\System32\wbem\scrcons.exe

Comment: I suggest you try scanning with another AV tool, e.g. MalwareBytes (https://www.malwarebytes.com). Also, see http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit

Comment: @James Thanks, I will install malwarebytes trial, hope there won't be any conflicts with (the stupid) avast.

Comment: You don't have to go to "funny" websites to download malware, most malware is sent through, ads

Comment: I have ran MBAM and disabled WSH and today that warning popped up again... Not sure what else can I do.

Comment: @Cristy: Try using a couple of bootable anti-virus ISO's (see the link to the SuperUser question in my previous comment) in case you have a rootkit deeply embedded in your system and your symptoms are just the tip of the iceberg.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a malicious VBScript is hooked somehow to your WMI event system - that is what `scrcons.exe` is responsible for - [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Using a free version of [MBAM](http://malwarebytes.org/) is a good idea, I would start with that.

You can allways check URL with [Virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com).

For the mentioned url `mst.my03.com` you get:

```
Dr.Web                  known infection source
Websense ThreatSeeker   dynamic dns
```

So it looks likely it is not a false alarm, it is a vbscript downloader.

One thing you can also do before you get rid of the rogue script completely is [to temporarily disable WSH](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198684.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Thanks, I disabled WSH. Is there any drawback if I keep WSH disabled?

Comment: No older scripting llanguages ike VBScripts, JScript will work, BAT or PowerShell should be ok. It may be problem when you install something that uses VBScripts during install.

Comment: I have ran MBAM and disabled WSH and today that warning popped up again... Not sure what else can I do.

Comment: Perhaps disabling did not work, you can verify by running a vbs file, containing *MsgBox "ok"*. Or the virus is only detected as vbscript but it is not a script at all.

Comment: It's disabled, if I type `cscript.exe` I get this: `CScript Error: Windows Script Host access is disabled on this machine. Contact your administrator for details.`

Comment: So it is some executable that is hooked to WMI event, MBAM did not show anything?

Comment: It did show and fix a few threats, but they seemed unrelated with this issue.

Comment: You may try to post your C:\Windows\System32\wbem\scrcons.exe on VirusTotal.com. There is a huge number or VBS:Downloader variants on Avast from AAA to AHK. You can also eventually block the one website http://superuser.com/questions/270524/blocking-web-sites-with-windows-firewall

Comment: Oddly, I can not select that `.exe` file to be uploaded on VirusTotal

Comment: I think this is related: http://la.trendmicro.com/media/misc/understanding-wmi-malware-research-paper-en.pdf but I didn't understand how to fix the issue.

Comment: `can not select that .exe` it is not in `C:\Windows\System32\wbem\scrcons.exe` or what? I do not have it on Windows 7 Enterprise x64 at all. What is your Windows version? You may try to uninstall KB2506143

Comment: I have the file, I can see it in File Explorer, but when I get the Upload file prompt and go to `System32\wbem` the scrcons.exe file does not appear in that menu. I have `Windows 10 Pro`. And from the guide on trendmicro I was not able to do anything as no Consumers appear in WMI.

Comment: You can drag and drop the file there...

Comment: `Warning! You submitted an empty file (0 bytes size), please make sure no software on your computer is preventing the upload (e.g. antivirus quarantine).` Message still appears if I disable the anti-virus

Comment: Also unable to copy the file to another destination on your disk with Avast disabled? That would be something very weird. More complex analysis of your system in terms of malware would be required.

Comment: Is it inside https://www.avast.com/faq.php?article=AVKB21 ?

Comment: No, it's not inside the virus chest. And I can copy it to another location and the file has 49KB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44873/discussion-between-vojtch-dohnal-and-cristy).