# Get notified when a specific IP address or website is accessed (windows 10)

Tags: security, firewall, notifications

My internet provider keeps sending me abuse notifications forwarded from Sony that says something like:

> Pursuant to Sony Network Entertainment International LLC (SNEI)
>   corporate policy, the below IP address was blacklisted from using our
>   services because SNEI detected activity that is abusive to our network
>   services. In our determination, the abusive activity was not related
>   to velocity or volume, but matched the specific patterns of known
>   abuse of our publicly available services. This abuse may be the result
>   of a computer on your network that has been compromised and is
>   participating in a botnet abuse of our services.It is most likely the
>   attack traffic is directed at one of the following endpoints:account.
>   sonyentertainmentnetwork. comauth.np.ac.playstation. netauth.api.
>   sonyentertainmentnetwork. comauth.api.np.ac.playstation. netThe
>   destination port will be TCP 443

I've run every virus scan known to mankind and still I keep getting these regularly. I'd like to get notified when these endpoints are accessed from my computer but I can't figure out how to do that. I've used the info in [this entry](https://superuser.com/questions/270524/blocking-web-sites-with-windows-firewall) to block these locations in windows firewall and I've tested it from my browser and it does block them. But it doesn't seem to log it the fact that it blocked it (at least not in Event Viewer or in the firewall that I can see). Nor does it pop up a onscreen notification (my browser just says the site is blocked). I'd really like to be notified so I can identify which process is doing this and get rid of it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't rule out a breach in security through a wireless access point etc.

Comment: If you keep getting them. Firstly change your router to block them not your PC. If you still keep getting them, tell your ISP that your router blocks them so it most certainly isn't you. Then get them to run a trace in their data centre. It is possible that someone is using your Wi-Fi (the router change blocks this) or someone is spoofing your IP (the ISP won't find the traffic unless it is someone else on the same network which they can trace).

Comment: Well it does appear to be coming from my laptop as everytime I've received a notice it corresponds to a time when my laptop was running. Never when just my roommates laptop or either or our phones were running. I did also try updating the wifi password and even the security mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

Well I dunno about Windows Firewall but  COMODO Firewall can do what you need. Block and log plus you can see what the process and what it wants. Very useful.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), particularly the bits in **bold**; then edit your answer to follow the guidelines there. Thanks!