# block websites on windows while maintaining access to admin and super-admin rights

Tags: windows, permissions, hosts, parental-controls

The motivation is to block myself from accessing certain distracting websites while still being able to add/remove programs, change settings etc. Can the built-in parental controls deliver this functionality.

Is this even possible in the windows security model? It seems like you'd have to create an account that duplicates all the privileges and functions of the "super-admin" account, but cannot unblock itself from accessing the websites.

(using windows 10)

Comment: No it is not possible. Anything which can be done by an admin account can be undone by another admin account.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this:

- Use [the *hosts* file](https://superuser.com/questions/270524/blocking-web-sites-with-windows-firewall) to block specific sites.
- Use [Windows Firewall](https://superuser.com/questions/270524/blocking-web-sites-with-windows-firewall) to block specific sites.
- Set permissions for sites using [*family* settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12439/microsoft-account-set-child-restrictions-windows-10-xbox-one), which apparently requires a Microsoft account, as opposed to local login.
- Use a third-party tool for a particular browser to block specific sites, such as [LeechBlock NG](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/leechblock-ng/) for Firefox.
- Use a third-party tool to block a category of sites for a particular browser, e.g. pornographic, such as [Porn/Malware Blocker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/porn-malware-blocker/) or [Porn site Blocker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/porn-site-blocker/) for Firefox.

Of course, anything you can install, you can uninstall... none of these options absolutely prevent you from undoing your New Year's resolution not to waste time on the web, but they're useful reminders.

Comment: Figures. Do you know if this is possible on linux or mac?

Comment: Again, intuitively obvious, anything you can install, you can uninstall. Perhaps an obliging ISP might block sites if you give someone power of attorney, to prevent *you* asking that they be unblocked... though I don't think it's likely.

Comment: it think the parental controls on ios allow you to install software while restricting web traffic.