# How to block a specific website in windows?

Tags: windows, vpn, firewall

I'm looking for a method to block a domain from my computer. I've find out that in windows I should put that domain in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.

something like this:

```
127.0.0.1     www.somewebsite.com
```

and this simply redirect that website to the localhost. but when i turn on a vpn I still have access to that website and that method doesn't work anymore. What can I do for that?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding a rule in Windows Firewall?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik No. How can I do that?

Comment: @MohammadHaji see this answer>>>>>https://superuser.com/a/749537/40928